# Losing MIME & other data when using the file() method on FileSystemFileEntry

Tags: javascript, html, loops, file, upload

I'm trying to convert FileSystemFileEntry's into files using the file() method and pushing them to an array, but I'm losing each file's MIME type (and I suspect more). This is causing the browser to not detect these objects as files.

When I log files in an array that haven't been converted with the file() method, we observe:
[screenshot of console (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyDQO.png)

When I log an array of converted files, we see:
[screenshot of console(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFdgV.png)

Later on in my code, when I attempt to loop over this array with:

```
    for (const [index, f] of selectedFiles.entries()) {
         console.log('run');
    }
```

Or even with a forEach(), nothing happens, and I suspect it's because I'm losing some data in this conversion process. This is causing me to not be able to manipulate this array of converted files. When using files that haven't been converted coming directly from an html input, I don't run into any issues.

Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

[See MDN's docs] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry).

Comment: UPDATE: This behaviour is not observed in Chrome. Is this a bug?

Comment: I just checked the console on Edge, Chrome and Firefox. I don't have a Mac, so I can't test it on Safari. However, what I'm noticing is that the console on firefox loses the MIME metadata and the other browsers don't. I guess I'll report a bug?

Comment: CONFIRMED: On Bugzilla, it's a bug that has been reported a long time ago and still not patch as of yet! Please get this fixed!

Comment: SOURCE: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424689

Comment: **FINAL UPDATE**: Super important. So this issue is half bug half bad code. I was console logging the files before they were ready. I fixed the problem by wrapping the .file() in a promise and waiting for the file to be ready, and the correct mime type is now observed. However, the console should still show the type, since Chrome & other browsers were not losing that metadata. I have some ideas why this occurs, but I'm not sure. **TAKEAWAY**: wrap your file() method in a promise and make sure you log it when it's ready!